# How to determine which application pool a SharePoint service application is running on in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to programmatically determine which application pool a service application is running on?  I haven't really found much on this so far.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone supplied me with a SharePoint specific answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46947/how-to-programmatically-determine-which-application-pool-a-service-application-i), but thanks everyone for your input.  The following code is how I got the application pool:

```
foreach (SPService service in SPFarm.Local.Services)
{
    if (service.Name.Equals("ServiceName"))
    {
        foreach (SPServiceApplication serviceApp in service.Applications)
        {
            SPIisWebServiceApplication webServiceApp = (SPIisWebServiceApplication) serviceApp;
            SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool appPool = webServiceApp.ApplicationPool;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IIS assigns the application to an app pool.  I don't know of a way to change the app pool programmatically or through configuration.

**EDIT:**  I take that back it looks like this is possible, this article may help you:
[Setup IIS programmaticaly](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/provisioning-sample-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code for IIS6, I am not sure though it will work for Sharepoint or another version of IIS...

```
public string GetAppPoolName() {
    string AppPath = Context.Request.ServerVariables["APPL_MD_PATH"];

    AppPath = AppPath.Replace("/LM/", "IIS://localhost/");
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(AppPath);
    if ((root == null)) {
        return " no object got";
    }
    string AppPoolId = (string)root.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value;
    return AppPoolId;
}
```

Copied from [How to detect what Application Pool I am currently running under? (IIS6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333391/how-to-detect-what-application-pool-i-am-currently-running-under-iis6?rq=1)